# Analogy between prime numbers and singleton sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

While trying -- in vain -- to write an alternative answer for another question ([If $\cup \mathcal{F}=A$ then $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Prove that $A$ has exactly one element.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/359550/11994)), I discovered the following property for sets: $$A \textrm{ is a singleton set} \;\equiv\; \langle \forall B : B \subseteq A : B = \emptyset \;\not\equiv\; B = A \rangle$$ and I noticed the similarity to the following definition for positive whole numbers: $$n \textrm{ is prime} \;\equiv\; \langle \forall d : d \textrm{ divides } n : d = 1 \;\not\equiv\; d = n\rangle$$  So it looks like singleton sets act a bit like prime numbers.  Which is not strange, come to think of it, given that both are 'indivisible atoms' of some sort.

So what common theory underlies both concepts of indivisibility?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about "affine schemes": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring, this might be part of the insight you're looking for

Comment: Dear @Cocopuffs:  Would you care to explain what affine schemes have to do with divisibility or singleton sets?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I'm worried it might not be the right way to understand the question. But the primes (or at least, prime ideals) become exactly the singleton sets in the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{Z}$ here, so maybe it shows that the correspondence is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can unify the two definitions by passing to their common generalisation in order theory. To begin, note that the set $\mathscr{P} (X)$ of all subsets of a fixed set $X$ is partially ordered by inclusion, and the set $P$ of all positive integers can be partially ordered by divisibility, and that both $\mathscr{P} (X)$ and $P$ has a bottom element ($\emptyset$ and $1$, respectively).

Moreover, both $\mathscr{P} (X)$ and $P$ have the property that, for any two elements $a$ and $b$, there exists a unique element $a \vee b$ such that, for all $c$ with $a \le c$ and $b \le c$, $a \vee b \le c$. In the case of $\mathscr{P} (X)$, this is the operation of taking the union of two subsets, and in the case of $P$, this is the operation of taking the l.c.m. of two numbers. A partially ordered set with a bottom element $\bot$ and this binary operation $\vee$ is said to be a **join semilattice**.

**Definition.** An **indecomposable element** of a join semilattice $L$ is an element $c$ such that, if $c = a \vee b$, then either $a = \bot$ or $a = c$ (but not both!).

As you have observed, the indecomposable elements of $\mathscr{P} (X)$ are precisely the singleton subsets, and the indecomposable elements of $P$ are precisely the prime numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P$ be the set of all prime numbers, and let $N$ be the collection of all multisets whose elements are in $P$.  Notice the fundamental theorem of arithmetic gives a bijection $N\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$, where $1$ corresponds to the empty multiset.

Under this bijection, the notion of divisibility of natural numbers corresponds to the notion of containment of sets, and the prime numbers correspond to singletons in $N$.  Also, notice that $\varnothing$ is contained in all elements of $N$, just as $1$ divides all natural numbers.

Comment: This is absolutely fascinating, if you have anything to add to this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877837/crazy-set-theory-analogies it would be great, I'm going through group and ring theoretical analogues similar to this if you have anything on that too it'd be awesome