# Crazy Set Theory Analogies

Tags: reference-request, big-list, lattice-orders

I think the following analogies are too interesting to be ignored:

- Union = Least Common Multiple

  If $G_1,...,G_n$ [denote](https://archive.org/stream/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich#page/n93/mode/2up) a number of sets of points (either linear or
  in any number of dimensions), the set which contains every point that
  belongs to one or more of the given sets is called their greatest
  common measure, and is denoted by $M(G_1,...,G_n)$. In case no two of
  the given sets have a point in common, the common measure of the sets
  may be denoted by $G_1 + G_2 + ...$ and it may be spoken of as their
  sum. By some writers the term "sum" is employed for the greatest
  common measure.
- Intersection = Greatest Common Divisor

  That set [which](https://archive.org/stream/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich#page/n93/mode/2up) contains all those points which belong to every one of
  the given sets is called their greatest common divisor, and it may be
  denoted by $D(G_1,...,G_n)$.
- Symmetric Difference

  A common operation in sets [is called](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ULwe2bPoMyUJ:ccgi.haloeye.net/In%2520the%2520Garden/Numbers1.htm%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ie&client=firefox-a) "symmetric difference". It is
  used in a special type of set called a boolean algebra. The basic
  operation on two sets is to subtract the intersection from the union.
  To do this in analogy to the integers is to divide the lcm by the
  gcd.
- Prime numbers = singleton sets

  [Analogy between prime numbers and singleton sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400573/analogy-between-prime-numbers-and-singleton-sets)
- Composite Number = Set with subsets (Divisor?)

  If all the points [of a set H](https://archive.org/stream/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich#page/n93/mode/2up) are points of a set G, H is said to be contained in G, or to be a part, or component, of G.
- Remainder = Complement?

  The set $G$ is said to contain $H$. Those points of $G$ that do not belong to $H$ form a set which may be denoted by $G-H$. The set $G-H$ is said to be the complement of $H$ with respect to $G$, and is sometimes denoted by $C_G(H)$.
- Derivative of a Set

  Returning to the case of a set $G$ in a finite interval or cell, we observe that the limiting points of $G$ form a set of points which may be finite or infinite; this set is called the derived set, or first derivative of $G$, and may be denoted by $G'$. In case the set $G$ contains an infinite number of points, it possesses itself a derivative set $G''$, which is called the second derivative of $G$. If we proceed in this manner, we may obtain a series $G',G'',...$ of derivatives of $G$. If the n'th derivative $G^n$ contains a finite number only of points, then these have no limiting point, and we may say that $G^{n+1}=0$
- $e^x$ = Perfect Set

  A set $G$ [which is both](https://archive.org/stream/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich#page/n93/mode/2up) closed and dense in itself is said to be perfect*. Thus a perfect set $G$ is identical with its derivative.

Does anybody have anymore of these? A reference perhaps? Comments? Can this be made more structured?

I don't really understand the denseness argument, but it sounds very similar to gauge invariance / or the additive constant of integration or something:

> If, [from any set](https://archive.org/stream/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich#page/n93/mode/2up) $G$, we remove those points which also belong to its
>   derivative, the remainder is an isolated set; thus $G - D(G,G')$ forms an
>   isolated set. Any set $G$ may be regarded as the sum of an isolated set
>   and of a component of the derivative $G$ . If a component $H$ of the set $G$
>   is such that every point of $G$ is a limiting point of $H$, the set $H$ is
>   said to be dense in $G$.

Comment: Most of them seem to be getting at lattice-theoretic notions.  However, I'm not quite sure what your question is at its base; the questions you do give make the question too broad.

Comment: What is the link between derivatives and derived sets, besides the name and the notation $f'$, $G'$?

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I think you're mostly noticing feature of mathematics -- we look at ways to "combine," "decompose," and "order" structures. Do you know abstract algebra? This is somewhere that these ideas start to be useful -- analogies between operations on rings and numbers abound. For instance, in ring theory, the notion of "prime" ideals generalizes that of a "prime" number, the sum of ideals generalizes the idea of a $gcd$, the intersection of ideals generalizes that of a $lcm$. (For the ring of integers, these ideas correspond exactly with the familiar operations).

Comment: So, $|$ (divides) is similar to $\in$ (belongs). I think such similarities are of interest to category theory.

Comment: Adding in this http://books.google.ie/books?id=Eq8ZualfMRkC&lpg=PA165&ots=Nik7DRxA9h&dq=Canotor%20derived%20set%20derivative&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q=Canotor%20derived%20set%20derivative&f=false description of a connected set as paralleling the notion of the limit of a function, I think the derivative as the limiting points of a set makes some sense!

Comment: I'm glad you see the jist of my point, but abstract algebra is based on set theory, where you are generalizing concepts like prime-ness to an ideal, a concept living in a *structure* which is more complicated/specialized entity than pure axiomatic set theory. In a similar fashion topology (e.g. derivative, connected set) are similar to abstract algebra, encoding more structure, as is lattice theory. All 3 are not set theory though, prime-ness applying in algebra does not necessarily mean it applies in set theory, whereas prime-ness applying in set theory means it applies in abstract algebra.

Comment: @Hayden I've stated what my question is: "Does anybody have anymore of these? A reference perhaps? Comments? Can this be made more structured?"

Comment: @bolbteppa Yes, and I'm saying that there are too many questions there without some underlying prime question, and so it seems to broad.

Comment: @bolbteppa, trying to characterize ideas about sets in terms of number-theoretic properties inevitably introduces algebra, since numbers *do* have additional algebraic structure. By finding "purely set-theoretic" analogies for fundamental properties and operations on numbers, you'll inevitably have algebraic structure lurking (see for instance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets) )...

Comment: ...If you seek an set-theoretic analogy for numbers and their properties that defies any implication of algebraic structure, it seems to me that it will necessarily be artificial. But it's still good to notice these things, and who knows -- maybe you will come up with a striking new theory!

Comment: I'm absolutely amazed that people are so unhappy with noticing relationships between different areas of mathematics, and just cannot handle a simple request for other things people have noticed. Not to sound like a (Cantor) crank but judging from the link to the book I gave above it seems Cantor used this kind of thinking to establish the importance of continuity in general topology, and judging by the old Hobson analysis book the early topologists thought along these similar lines. Coupling this with Lang's famous quote that analysis is merely 'number theory at infinity' there is definitely

Comment: something deep behind all of these analogies - who knows maybe Schroder-Bernstein is just the application of the mumber-theoretic mobius function to the context of set theory :p That's all I'm hoping to find out about, apparently only early 20'th century research mathematicians have the capacity to appreciate my question :( [Referring to votes to close, of course]

Comment: I believe the original symbols used by Cantor for union and intersection was based on this analogy, and they may have been suggested by (or perhaps just indirectly influenced by) Dedekind. José Ferreirós discusses the number-theoretic origins of union and intersection in his book [**Labyrinth of Thought**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/3764383496), but I don't have my copy with me to look at right now.

Answer (score 0):

A few people have mentioned, if you study abstract algebra, then you know that integers form a ring under addition and multiplication. If you go on further to study some [category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) then you will see that it is not surprising because, to put it vaguely, you can try to find bijections between the sets of different algebraic structures. Category theory formalises these patterns.

And yes, you can take other algebraic structures as well. [Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-058-00/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6.pdf) is a link to the first paper written on this, if you're interested in reading it. I don't know what your background is but it might be helpful to know something about more than one algebraic structure (vector spaces, groups, rings etc.) so you have pet examples to examine this concept in more detail.

What you start with is something called a category. A category takes some notions of structure we see and formalises them. For example a group, or natural numbers, or a set. But then this structure itself can be seen as an object to be put in a category called a functor. So the set of sets, or the set of groups with a certain property. You can then take something called a natural transformation. As wikipedia says: "Abstracting yet again, some diagrammatic and/or sequential constructions are often "naturally related" – a vague notion, at first sight. This leads to the clarifying concept of natural transformation, a way to "map" one functor to another. Many important constructions in mathematics can be studied in this context. "Naturality" is a principle, like general covariance in physics, that cuts deeper than is initially apparent. An arrow between two functors is a natural transformation when it is subject to certain naturality or commutativity conditions."

Comment: So can you use any of that to describe other axiomatic set theory or point set topology notions analogously to the way I've described all those concepts above?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that pdf does not address my question. Can you explain to me in your own words how category theory formalizes the relationship of the exponential function with the topological concept of a perfect set, or perhaps mention some other basic set-theoretic concepts that have number-theoretic analogues (using category theory if you really think that it the right way to do it), instead of telling me that category theory has the potential to answer my question, without actually concretely doing it?

Comment: I don't know if you're still interested but while I don't know very much about this beautiful field myself I can try. Check edits!