# If $\bigcup F = A$ then $A\in F$ then prove that $A$ has exactly one element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

This is one question which has been asked in Velleman's How to prove book:

> Suppose $A$ is a set, and for every family of sets $F$, if $\cup F = A$ then $A ∈
> F$. Prove that $A$ has exactly one element

This question has been already proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359550/if-cup-mathcalf-a-then-a-in-mathcalf-prove-that-a-has-exactly-one) but isn't something like this an counterexample of the proof:

$ F = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$ A = \{1,2\} $

Now,

$ \cup F = \{1,2\}$

and also $A \in F$ but $A$ has more than one element.

Is my counterexample valid ?

Comment: Your counterexample is not valid. Take the family $F=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$. $\cup F=A$ but $A\notin F$. Your set $A$ does not satisfy the original condition.

Comment: @EdwardJiang What's the error in taking $ F = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$  ?

Comment: The condition is for *every* family $F$, not just for one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the statement is *every* family of sets. To see why your argument is a mistake, and why this statement is in fact true, consider the following hint.

**HINT:** Given any non-empty set $A$, then $A=\bigcup\{\{a\}\mid a\in A\}$.

Comment: Hint2: admitting your hypothesis, and being the first hint true, assume by contradiction $A$ having two or more elements...